# How I use Appodeal.Native

Tags: android, ads

Anyone know an easy example to use `Appodeal.Native`, I'm trying to use but I'm having some problems (I'm new on this). I found this 2 examples, but first one is too complicated and the second did not worked...

[first](https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-android-demo)

[second](https://github.com/TheAnimatrix/Appodeal_test)

Anyone can explain how I should do or indicate a link with a easy example... Really Thx.

Comment: I would like to know too. Because I did not get it either.